# Ошибка соединения с базой данных Drupal

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo, drupal

Не понимаю как правильно подключиться к базе данных drupal из стороннего скрипта:

```
<?php
require("database.inc");
$result = db_query("...");
```

При выполнении кода выскакивает ошибка:

> Uncaught DatabaseConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified database
> connection is not defined: default

Comment: друпал разных версий бывает..

Comment: Версия Drupal 7.4.0

Comment: тут посмтри https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-05-26/connect-to-drupal-database-from

Comment: гугли "connect to drupal database from outside"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
?>
```